# Python time to reconvert to same data type

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion

I'm iterating through a huge list of unknown data types (mostly integers) using Python. So in order to standardize the data type, I usually convert the variable into an int. So my question is in case of large lists, does it take extra time to convert an int to an int? More formally consider the following code:

```
# data is a huge list which consists of int, float etc.
modifieddata=[]
for i in data:
 modifieddata.append(int(i)+12)
```

Here if i is already an int what exactly does python do? Does it waste time to convert it back to an int or does it just ignore the int() statement?

Comment: as far as I know, if i in your data is an int, then python recognises it is in an int and skips it. But to recognise it, it does take time but not as much as converting to an int.

Comment: By the way, your code is exactly right.  In Python, if you want to make sure something is an `int` you just wrap it in `int()` always, rather than checking the type and forcing it if the type isn't right.  This makes "Duck Typing" work: as long as the value `i` can be forced to an `int` the code will work, so there is no need to check the type of `i`.  Just coerce it to what you need it to be.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that Python will not waste any time in converting an `int` to an `int`.  Python will check the type, and if it is already an `int` will just leave it alone.

When Python creates new objects, it must allocate memory and keep track of references.  So needlessly converting by creating a new object would cause needless slowdown by making the memory allocator and garbage collector work extra.

At least in CPython, Python actually re-uses the most common integers.  If you compute `3 - 3` you will get back `0` and it will actually be the same object as every other `0`.

```
x = 0
y = 3 - 3
assert x is y  # they are the same object!
```

Note: I wouldn't count on the above; it happens to work now but it's not a good idea to rely on it.  But if Python is taking the trouble to re-use common integers rather than allocate new ones, you know Python won't be taking integers and pointlessly re-allocating them.

Comment: Seems legit :) But have you ever come across a more "formal" assertion (some documentation maybe) of the fact that Python doesn't "waste" time?

Comment: I haven't really researched this... there are two things you could do: (0) use the `timeit` module to measure the actual speed hit from passing an `int` value to `int()` by running one loop that sums up values from `xrange()` or `range()` and a similar loop that also pointlessly passes the `int` values to `int()`; (1) get the source code to Python and see what it actually does.